# Lombok Builder.Default not initiated for inner class

Tags: lombok

I have an issue to initiate an inner class's attribute when building the outer class. For example I have following classes and when I do `A.builder().build()`, I expect to have `A.classB.type = "temporary"` but it is actually null. What am I doing wrong? It only works when I do `A.builder().classB(B.builder().build()).build()`

```java
    @SuperBuilder
    @Getter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    public static class A {
        private final long id;
        private final B classB;
    }

    @SuperBuilder
    @Getter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    public static class B {
        @Builder.Default
        private final String type = "temporary";
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is `null`? Looking at your code, I expect `classB` to be `null`, not `classB.type`.

Comment: you are right! I need to add `@Builder.Default` to B field and set classB to `private final B classB = B.builder().build;`